# How prove $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$

Tags: analysis

show that: every function $h(x):R\to R$ can be written as
$$h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$$
where $f(x),g(x)$ are satisfying the   intermediate value property：

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem

My try: since  $f(x),g(x)$ are all  such Intermediate value theorem

**mean that:**

so for $f(x)$,and for  any $[a,b]$, there exsit $\xi\in(a,b)$,such
$$f(\xi)=\eta,$$
where $f(a)<\eta<f(b)$

similar
for $g(x)$,and for any $[c,d]$,there $\xi_{1}\in[c,d]$,such
$$f(\xi_{1})=\eta_{1}$$
where $\eta_{1}\in (f(c),f(d))$

and Now How can for any function $h(x)$,then  we always can 
$$h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$$
Thank you

Comment: What does 'are all such Intermediate value theorem' mean?

Comment: Hello,My try is explain.Thank you

Comment: The problem is solved on page 77 of Andreescu and Gelca, Mathematical Olympiad Challenges.

Comment: @copper.hat: The meaning must be that $f$ and $g$ have the _intermediate value property_ (aka they are "Darboux functions").

Comment: @GerryMyerson,Oh,Thank you,

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Thanks, that helps.

Comment: Can someone edit the question? Its hard to read/understand.

Answer (score 1):

That is *[Sierpinski’s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wac%C5%82aw_Sierpi%C5%84ski)* Theorem and you can find it on *Beni Bogoşel* blog [over here](http://mathproblems123.wordpress.com/2009/09/08/sierpinskis-theorem/).

(For your case, you need redefine $f_1$ and $f_2$ that mentioned there.)

**Edit:**

Theorem 3 in: [Darboux functions - Beni Bogoşel.pdf](http://mathproblems123.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/strange-functions.pdf)

Comment: Hello,you link this blog,I can't open it,Thank you

Comment: @math110: It is basically the same construction as the one I hint at in my answer.

Comment: I find this book have proof: http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=fXfEG-F2zJUC&pg=PA6&redir_esc=y&hl=zh-CN&sourceid=cndr#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: @math110: see the link to pdf file.

Comment: @SalechAlhasov,Thank you,also can't open it

Answer (score 0):

Using the axiom of choice, you can achieve something stronger, namely that the image of *any nonempty interval* under $f$ and $g$ is *all the real numbers*.

**Hint:** Start by choosing a basis for $\mathbb R$ as a vector space over $\mathbb Q$. Then partition $\mathbb R$ into two dense locally continuum-sized sets $A$ and $B$, and make sure that $f$ will take all values on $(x,y)\cap A$ for any $x<y$ and $g$ will take all values on $(x,y)\cap B$ for any $x<y$. Then choose the values of $f$ on $B$ and $g$ on $A$ such that their difference is the desired $h$.